# Boolean will not change no matter what

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

```
 void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col)
 {
 if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy1" ) {
 enemyContact = true;
 Debug.Log ("shot has collided with tagged enemy");
 }
 }
```

The problem is that I know the collision is successful in that the debug shows up, but enemy contact will NOT turn true. Once it is true the enemy dies, and if I set it to true in Awake, this is proved to be true.

But how, can the the program be getting to the debug but still refuse to turn the Boolean to true???

I must be losing my mind.

I've also tried:

```
 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
 {
     if (other.tag == "Enemy1")
     {
         enemyContact = true;
         Debug.Log ("trigger enter worked");
     }
 }
```

The variable will not change. Again, even though the debug log shows up on contact, the variable will not change.

I have also tried:

```
 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D CollisionCheck)
 {
     if (CollisionCheck.gameObject.tag == "Enemy1") {
         Debug.Log ("shot has collided with tagged enemy");

         enemyContact = true;
     }
 }
```

The variable will not change to true. No matter what. 
Even tried:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col)
     {
         if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy1" ) {

             Debug.Log ("shot has collided with tagged enemy");
             if (enemyContact == false){
                 enemyContactFunction();

         }    
     }

 void enemyContactFunction(){
         enemyContact = true;
     }
```

The debug again goes off but the function will not run, and the variable stays unchanged. The variable is public and I can watch it. I don't know what else to add. Here is the entire script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShotScript : MonoBehaviour {
public Player pScript;
public Vector2 velocityRight = new Vector2(5, 0);
public Vector2 velocityLeft = new Vector2(-5, 0);
public Vector2 velocityUp = new Vector2(0, 5);
public Vector2 velocityDown = new Vector2(0,-5);

public Vector2 velocityupRight = new Vector2(5, 5);
public Vector2 velocityupLeft = new Vector2(-5, 5);
public Vector2 velocitydownRight = new Vector2(5,-5);
public Vector2 velocitydownLeft = new Vector2(-5,-5);

private Rigidbody2D shotRigid;



public bool enemyContact = false;
public bool enemyContactTrue = false;

void Awake()
{
    shotRigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();

}

void Start()
{

    //checking which direction player is facing to decide which way to shoot
    shotRigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();

}

void enemyContactFunction(){
    enemyContact = true;
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy1" ) {

        Debug.Log ("shot has collided with tagged enemy");
        if (enemyContact == false){
            enemyContactFunction();

    }   
}

} }
```

Comment: Seems like you're having some trouble with variable scope.  Where is enemyContact declared?

Comment: Yes, I'd want to see where enemyContact is declared, and also whether it might have a name clash with something else in your program. Can you print out the full results of a search for enemyContact in your codebase?

Comment: Sorry I can't get the reply box here to format that, but that is where it is declared. I doubt it is conflicting with any other instance of enemyContact, it is a new variable in a new script for one function. 
I don't understand what you mean by print out the results of a search for enemyContact - do you mean what appears in the console when the collision takes place? It just prints the debug and nothing else. I will post the full script.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the class that has these methods, including how that boolean variable is declared?

Comment: I posted the script, still can't figure anything out. Hope that helps...I've spent almost 2 days trying to find out how to change a single variable!

Comment: Change `Debug.Log ("shot has collided with tagged enemy");` to `Debug.Log("enemyContact: " + enemyContact);` to see the actual state of the variable at the time. As it is, the variable might just be changed back to false before your other code can get to it.

Comment: Ok, this is what happened when I did that, maybe a clue. In the console it says this:
enemyContact: False
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

And then
made it to enemyContactFunction
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
ShotScript:enemyContactFunction() (at Assets/Scripts/ShotScript.cs:80)
ShotScript:OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D) (at Assets/Scripts/ShotScript.cs:90)

I am just blown away though, it is such a simple script, really no one knows why? If anyone else wanted to change a single boolean using a collision, what would they do???

Comment: Ok well here is something new, if I just drag a prefab of the shot into the scene, and the enemies hit that, then the script runs fine. It must be something about how my shot is instantiating from player? Here is where that takes place: if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.R) && moveRight != false) { // nextFire = Time.time + fireRate; Instantiate(shot, shotSpawnRight.position, shotSpawnRight.rotation);

Comment: And that line is after the enemyContact = true; ? Also, you have one instance of the bullet, because maybe you are looking at the wrong one.